# Framework for social graph in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nosql, social-networking, social-graph

I would like to have a database for social graph in my Rails app. Hopefully, the app will eventually have a few hundred of thousands of users, plus their Facebook and LinkedIn connections. Right now, I am using MySQL, but I know it is not efficient in dealing with social graph.

How should I go about this, and which framework/gems etc. that work with Rails and have been well tested?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You might look into

http://neo4j.org

...which is a graph database designed to handle storing, sorting, finding relationships in graph data.  A good introduction:

http://markorodriguez.com/2012/03/07/exploring-wikipedia-with-gremlin-graph-traversals/

Ruby bindings:

https://github.com/andreasronge/neo4j